# Substring of string reuses storage of original string?

Tags: swift

I was going through the Strings and characters section of the [swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Here it is mentioned:

> substrings aren’t suitable for long-term storage—because they reuse
>   the storage of the original string, the entire original string must be
>   kept in memory as long as any of its substrings are being used.

I tried testing this in the playground but what happened seems to be different from what is mentioned above. I ran the following code in playground:

```
var greeting : String? = "Hello, world!"
let index = greeting!.firstIndex(of: ",") ?? greeting!.endIndex
let beginning = greeting?[..<index]
print(beginning ?? "")
greeting = nil
print(beginning ?? "")
```

What i expected to be printed:

```
"Hello"
""
```

But what exactly was printed was:

```
"Hello"
"Hello"
```

Shouldn't have setting the original string to nil caused the substring to be removed as well?

Comment: If `beginning` became `nil` just because `greeting` was set to `nil`, it would cause some nasty and confusing bugs.

Comment: @rmaddy agreed, thats why i checked it in the playground, but the confusing part is that doesn't that directly go against what i quoted?

Comment: Not at all. It actually confirms it. You still have a reference to the substring so, as stated in what you quoted, the original string is still kept in memory. And this is true despite you no longer having an explicit reference to the original string.

Comment: Ah i see, i didn't think that the reference will be shared and won't be removed from memory automatically.

Comment: I think the docs should have mentioned, "the entire original string is kept in memory as long as any of its substrings are being used." It would make it more grammatically correct and explain why the substring is still alive even explicitly destroying the parent string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is correct.

The substring shares the reference counter of the original string. If the original string is destroyed the reference is still alive.

Please watch [WWDC 2017: What's new in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/402/) from 36:00

And actually even the quoted text confirms that behavior because it says that after slicing a string the entire string is kept in memory.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your test confirms the issue you quoted: Keeping a substring keeps a strong reference to the original string, so it does not get deallocated.

Imagine that the original string was the entire text from "War and Peace" and you got a substring containing the first occurrence of "and". The entire text of War and Peace would stay in memory as long as you kept that substring.

You can avoid the strong reference by converting the substring to a regular String:

```
let beginning = String(greeting?[..<index])
```

Comment: Yea, i interpreted the quote as dereferencing the original string would remove the substring from memory instead of the substring maintaining the reference to the original string.